Function for clamping an angle
I want a function to return a value in the range [0, tau) for any given finite number.
Naively I would write
const TAU = Math.PI * 2;
function clamp(theta) {
    while(theta < 0) theta += TAU;
    return theta % TAU;
}

However, I note that this is constant time for positive theta and linear time for negative theta.  Is there a solution that is O(1) for all input values?

How does % works in your language for negative argument?
In Python it gives modulo, and
def clamp(theta):
   return theta % TAU

returns needed  result (for example, same results for pi/2, 5*pi/2, -3*pi/2)
If % is remainder, you can use the next expression (as recommended for JS) to make corrections for negative results:
((theta % TAU) + TAU) % TAU

